# Is it possible to install geth as a Windows service and connect to it using the Wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have had limited success running **geth** as a Windows Service. I have used [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) to install it as a Service and it will start. However, when I open a Command Window and attempt to use "geth attach" I always receive "*Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: Access is denied.*" as my result.

I can run geth manually from one Command Window and use "geth attach" from a separate Command Window and it will attach successfully.

Does anyone know how if there are additional commands I can put in the service start-up to open up access?

EDIT: it looks like I am actually suffering from a well-known issue: "*system service session isolation in NT6+*" if anyone knows how to overcome this, please reply.

Comment: Well, I don't know about Windows service, but after running geth with enabled rpc, you can connect Mist to it with `mist.exe --rpc http://localhost:8545`